# Angular chartjs multiple chart types

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have imported the lib: [angular-chart.js](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/)

Now i am trying to make a chart that contains both a `bar graph and a line graph`

Sadly though the documentation does not specify how i can achieve this.

Does anyone have any experience with this and know how i can accomplish the issue?
 And know if it is even possible since the creating is rather different since you are using 1 `canvas` to contain your chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Highcharts ng

Here is [Angular Highcharts](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng)

Highchart bar-line chart example [Bar-line](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo)